# Detect dynamic div elements with getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, getelementbyid

So when the code ...

```
document.getElementById('classhere').childNodes
```

... runs, I manage to get all elements with that ID EXCEPT for elements that have been dynamically created by a 'createDiv()' function:

```
function createDiv()
{
  var divTag = document.createElement("div");
  divTag.id = "classhere" + num;
...
```

I would like to get all div elements with that Id, even dynamically created div elements. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your div is already created?

Comment: Are you adding the dynamically created div to page DOM? can you post your entire `createDiv` function and the code part where you creating new divs

Answer (score 0):

Try out jQuery 
jQuery Wildcard Selector
http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/07/25/jquery-wildcard-selector/

Answer (score 0):

> So when the code ...
>   
> `document.getElementById('classhere').childNodes`
>   
> ... runs, I manage to get all elements with that ID

[`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-getElBId) looks up a single element *by ID*, not by class. That line as quoted will look up an element with the `id` value "classhere" and return a [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-536297177) of its immediate child nodes (elements, text nodes, etc.). If you create further elements and either don't add them to the DOM, or add them elsewhere (not as immediate children of the "classhere" element), they won't be on the `NodeList`. It has nothing to do with whether they were created during the main HTML parsing or after-the-fact with JavaScript.

> I would like to get all div elements with that Id...

There can be only **one** element with a given ID.

If you're trying to find all elements whose `id` *starts with* "classname", you can use an ["attribute starts with selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
var divs = $("div[id^='classname']");
```

...gives you a jQuery object containing all of the matching divs as of the time you executed the statement (unlike a `NodeList`, it's not live; if you change things you'll have to run the selector again).